# Android using new version catalog to add local modules

Tags: android, gradle

I've created a new project with new `libs.versions.toml` file, then added a `core` module, then I've added it as dependency, into `app` module's `build.gradle.kts` file using the following code:

```
implementation(project(":core"))
// other libs using version catalog:
implementation(libs.core.ktx)
implementation(libs.appcompat)
implementation(libs.material)
```

Everything works fine, now I'm looking for a way to add the `:core` module inside the `libs.versions.toml` file and unify adding dependencies, think about **`:core:data`** module for instance, and implementation like it:

```
implementation(libs.local.core.data)
```

Comment: Yes @ErfanEghterafi, you can check the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I came up with a solution that can be applied to **non-version-catalog** projects as well:

1- in your `settings.gradle(.kts)` add `enableFeaturePreview` somewhere at the root block of the file:

```kotlin
enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")

rootProject.name = "MyApplication"
include(":app")
include(":core:data")
```

2- Now you'll be able to have **AutoCompilation** for all local modules, using the `projects` keyword. Then use it like this (in `app` `build.gradle(.kts)`):

```
dependencies {
    implementation(projects.core.data)

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    // ...
}
```